# Rotated text hugging edge of another div/screen

Tags: html, css, rotation, positioning

I have a div with some text inside (in another div). I'd like for the text to be rotated 90 degrees and hugging the edge of the parent div, only it's not working. Since (to me it seems this way at least) the browser looks at the width of the div before it's been rotated and thus I can't place the text any closer to the edge than what the width would allow had it not been rotated at all.

I have used the transform:rotate() attribute to rotate the text, and I have it floated to the right.

Comment: Little of the CSS would be <3

Comment: what have you tried, no html, no css , it is only guess. somthing like this maybe : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/HynLe ?